# Should I store foreign key table as foreign key ID or the C# model of that table in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

The title is a bit confusing but I couldn't think of any other way to put it. So I'll explain with an example.

Let's say I have a `Student` class, a `Student` belongs to a `School` class and a `School` can have many students. What we then tend to write for the `School` model is:

```
public class School
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

And for the `Student` model:

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual School School { get; set; }
}
```

So you can see that instead of having a **foreign key** `SchoolID` in `Student` class, we have an **actual `School` object** mapped thanks to EF magic, and it's marked virtual so it's lazy-loaded too.

Now does this mean that using EF we are safe to eliminate all foreign key IDs in a POCO model and replace them with actual references to those objects? Will there be any downside to directly referencing the object instead of IDs?

Comment: Those POCOs are not well formed, the primary key must be decorated with [PrimaryKey], and thus, Entity framework uses that attribute from the related entity to determine the foreign key. At the end, no, you must always have a primary key

Comment: @Gusman Thanks Gusman. Yeah there will be primary keys for sure, those were just very simple examples. My question is really more about the necessity of foreign keys (IDs) :)

Comment: There's no need for you to create a SchoolId on the Student POCO, but EF will create the fields on the DB to create the relationships. If you want to change an student from school you just retrieve the correspondent schools and remove the item from one school and add it to the other, there should not be any downside.

Comment: Thanks man that makes sense and clears things out for me. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think eventually you'll need the foreign key property.
If the student changes school you will want to update the Associated property only by knowing the SchoolId.

Also,if you want to add a new Student to an existing school you'll have to load the School from the same context or else you'll end up with [duplicate records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895744/entity-framework-creating-new-data-rows-during-db-savechanges/24896109#24896109)

So, add the Foreign Key property too

```
public int SchoolId{ get; set; }
```

Comment: yeah you are right! I would need them for updating the entities. What if all my models are read-only though? would it then cause any issues?

Comment: I guess you could,but in that case I think it's better if you use different ViewModels/Models. You can use a tool like AutoMapper to Transform you Data Entities to the appropriate ViewModels/Models ,it's not really too much trouble